# Calculate Percent Change Between Rows in Pandas Grouped by Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am somewhat new to Pandas and I have been stuck on a problem.

Assume I have the following dataframe (df1):

| Name | Day | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Al | Monday | 75 |
| Al | Friday | 88 |
| Bo | Monday | 90 |
| Bo | Friday | 100 |
| Cy | Monday | 85 |
| Cy | Friday | 95 |

I would like to create another dataframe (df2) with each person's name and their percent improvement from Monday to Friday.

The result would be:

| Name | Improvement |
| --- | --- |
| Al | 17.33 |
| Bo | 11.11 |
| Cy | 11.76 |

For example, Al improved by 17.33% between Monday and Friday (((88-75)/75) * 100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is for each `Name` always ordered `Monday` and `Friday` like in sample data solution is [`GroupBy.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.pct_change.html):

```
df = (df[['Name']].join(df.groupby('Name')['Score'].pct_change().mul(100)
                          .rename('Improvement'))
                  .dropna())
print (df)
  Name  Improvement
1   Al    17.333333
3   Bo    11.111111
5   Cy    11.764706
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us pivot to reshape then calculate pct change along column axis

```
s = df.pivot('Name', 'Day', 'Score')
s = s.pct_change(-1, axis=1)['Friday'].reset_index(name='Improvement')
```

Result

```
  Name  Improvement
0   Al     0.173333
1   Bo     0.111111
2   Cy     0.117647
```